# Building MSI from TFS Build

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, windows-installer, devenv

I am trying to build MSIs in a TFS Build by shelling out to DEVENV.exe (since MSBUILD does not support VSPROJs).  In any case, my first installer project builds fine, the second one fails.  If I reverse the order, same thing happends (i.e. the error does not follow the project).  Looking at the output, I get the following errors:

```
Deserializing the project state for project '[MyProject].dbproj'
[MyProject].dbproj : error  : Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

Also, I get:

```
Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestCaseManagement.QualityToolsPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.TestCaseManagement, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' failed to load
```

It looks as though the first build tries to serialize the DB project (and it says it succeeds, but there is no DBML file anywhere).  Then the second build tries to deserialize the DB project and fails.

I've tried resetting env settings (using the /resetusersettings flag) as well as using the /resetskippkgs flag.  Nothing works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

When you shell out to DevEnv, are you building that specific project (.vdproj file), or are you building the solution? It sounds like VS is trying to open the solution on the build machine and the database and test project systems aren't present.

Have you considered porting your setup project to WiX?

Answer (score 3):

Start simple. Unless you're well versed in the problem you're trying to solve it's usually best to try it "by hand" before getting it running as part of a TFS build. RDP into the build server and try running the necessary commands at the command line and see what happens. You can even go simpler than that and RDP into the build machine and load Visual Studio and build it.

Bottom line is that if you can't get it to build within Visual Studio or at the command line by calling devenv.exe it won't work as part of the team build.

I am using the below Exec task to do precisely what you are doing as part of a TFS build. So I know this works. Your platform and configuration may vary depending on what you're building. The nice thing about this is that you'll have a log file at C:\Temp\MSIBuildOutputLog.txt that you can analyze for additional errors and information.

```
<Exec Command="&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe&quot; &quot;$(PathToSolution)\solution.sln&quot; /Build &quot;Release|Mixed Platforms&quot; /out &quot;C:\Temp\MSIBuildOutputLog.txt&quot;" />
```

One important thing to note... **There is a bug in VS2010 which causes MSI generation to fail when you try to run it at the command line using devenv.exe**. This took me days to find and figure out, but you need this hotfix. Worked like a charm...
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB2286556

Comment: Thanks fro the info.  Everything works if I just build one MSI (so I know TFS/logging/etc. is setup right.  When I RDP into the box and execute the commands manually the same thing happens.  I can, however build by opening Visual Studio and running it there.

Comment: Just based on my personal experience with there being a difference between behavior when building via Visual Studio and building via command line devenv.exe you might want to try that hotfix I mentioned. It's a low risk change on your build server. Other than that... if you can always get one MSI to build you might want to just setup two separate build definitions (one for each MSI) and be done with it. It's not ideal, but trying to troubleshoot the differences between Visual Studio functionality in IDE mode and command line mode isn't ideal either. :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's the deployment projects that don't support msbuild.  FWIW, this is all deprecated in the next release of Visual Studio so you might want to start looking at InstallShield Limited Edition and/or Windows Installer XML now before spending too much time on dead end, broken technology.  Both of these alternatives have proper MSBuild support aswell as many other improvements.

Answer (score 0):

It would be perhaps better and quicker to adopt WIX (Windows Installer XML) which is the technology MS now recommends to use within VS/MSBuild/TFSBuild environment to crate MSIs.

It is relatively easy to setup and integrate within your VS Solutions. It uses XML based files  to describe your MSIs and uses these files to create your MSIs when you compile.

I would start by downloading Wix from http://wix.codeplex.com/

Once installed you would be able to use the VS2010 integration of Wix based projects to create MSIs. To get started quickly simply add a new Wix project to your solution and reference the projects whose output you wish to combine into an MSI. Next you can run a tool called "Heat" which is included with Wix toolkit to generate the XML files by scanning your projects.

Once you have these XML files, add them to your Wix project and compile.